# How to iterate first line in regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have this example:

```
[Some text here]

$$ABC=2017-08-11

$$CDE=2019-01-01

$$FGH=2015-09-10

$$IJK=2014-04-12

[More text again]

$$LMN=2014-03-30

opq.$$rst=2014-07-20

uvw.xyz=2014-09-10

$$AEI=5
```

My regex should match everything and return this:

```
[Some text here] - $$ABC - 2017-08-11

[Some text here] - $$CDE - 2019-01-01

[Some text here] - $$FGH - 2015-09-10

[Some text here] - $$IJK - 2014-04-12

[More text again] - $$LMN - 2014-03-30

[More text again] - opq.$$rst - 2014-07-20

[More text again] - uvw.xyz - 2014-09-10

[More text again] - $$AEI - 5
```

How can I do this? Is even possible iterate the text in brackets and return it every line? I'm using c#.

I'hve already tried this pattern:

```
(\[.+?\])(.*(?=\[)|.*)
```

But I'm so far from what I want. I get this result:

[Some text here] - $$ABC=2017-08-11

```
               $$CDE=2019-01-01

               $$FGH=2015-09-10

               $$IJK=2014-04-12
```

[More text again] - $$LMN=2014-03-30

```
                opq.$$rst=2014-07-20

                uvw.xyz=2014-09-10

                $$AEI=5
```

Comment: Pure regex cannot do this. You need to apply programming logic.

Comment: Looks as if you use `Regex.Split(text, @"(\[.+?\])(.*(?=\[)|.*)")` right?

Comment: Try `var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<=(\[[^][]+])(?s:.*?))[\r\n]+([^\n\r=]+)=(.*)").Cast<Match>().Select(x => $"{x.Groups[1].Value} - {x.Groups[2].Value} - {x.Groups[3].Value}").ToList()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may use

```
var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<=(\[[^][]+])(?s:.*?))[\r\n]+([^\n\r=]+)=(.*)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => $"{x.Groups[1].Value} - {x.Groups[2].Value} - {x.Groups[3].Value}")
    .ToList();
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%28%5C%5B%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D%2B%5D%29%28%3Fs%3A.*%3F%29%29%5B%5Cr%5Cn%5D%2B%28%5B%5E%5Cn%5Cr%3D%5D%2B%29%3D%28.*%29&i=%5BSome%20text%20here%5D%0D%0A%24%24ABC%3D2017-08-11%0D%0A%24%24CDE%3D2019-01-01%0D%0A%24%24FGH%3D2015-09-10%0D%0A%24%24IJK%3D2014-04-12%0D%0A%5BMore%20text%20again%5D%0D%0A%24%24LMN%3D2014-03-30%0D%0Aopq.%24%24rst%3D2014-07-20%0D%0Auvw.xyz%3D2014-09-10%0D%0A%24%24AEI%3D5).

**Details**

- `(?<=(\[[^][]+])(?s:.*?))` - positive lookbehind finds the closest `[...]` substring on the left of the subsequent subpatterns and captures it into Group 1 (`(?s:.*?)` allows the string to appear anywhere on the left, after any 0+ chars (`(?s:...)` allows `.` to match any chars including newlines)
- `[\r\n]+` - matches 1+ CR or LF chars, linebreaks
- `([^\n\r=]+)` - Capturing group 2: 1+ chars other than line break chars and `=`
- `=`  - a `=` char
- `(.*)` - Group 3: the rest of the line.

The groups are concatenated into `... - ... - ...` string upon a match and a list is returned.

Comment: This was perfect! Thanks so much!